# Function returns an empty array

Tags: node.js

i can't find the bug in this function. It returns every time an empty array.
Hope someone can help me.

https://gist.github.com/podkopaev/8406346

```
portal.getHosterByStream = function(stream, callback) {
    request(URL + stream, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var hoster = [];
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var information = $('body div[id=frmMain] div[id=dontbeevil] div[id=Vadda]').html();
            var items_hoster = $(information).find("ul[id=HosterList]").html();

            $(items_hoster).each(function (i, item) {
                var rel = $(item).attr('rel');

                if (rel != undefined) {
                    request(MIRROR + rel, function (error, response, body) {
                        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                            var host = JSON.parse(body);

                            var href = "";
                            var positionHref = 9;
                            var i = 0;

                            while (host.Stream.substr(positionHref + i, 1) != '"') {
                                href = util.format('%s%s', href, host.Stream.substr(positionHref + i, 1));

                                i++;
                            }
                            hoster.push(href);
                        } else {
                            console.log('error second request');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            callback(hoster);
        } else {
            console.log('error request page');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request()` is async, so you're calling `callback(hoster)` before any of your `hoster.push(href)` calls get a chance to execute.

So change your code to not call `callback(hoster)` until all of your `request()` callbacks have completed.

**UPDATE**

In your latest gist, you're calling `callback(null, 103);` before your `request` calls have called their callbacks and populated `hoster`.

Instead of `rel.forEach`, use [`async.eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries) in a pattern like:

```
async.eachSeries(rel, function(item, cb) {
        request(MIRROR + item, function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                ...
                hoster.push(href);
            }
            cb();
        });
    }, function(err) {
        // This won't get called until all the request callbacks are done.
        callback(null, 103);
    }
);
```

Comment: could you please help me with the code. i am new to node.js and trying to fix this bug for a week now.

Comment: @user3197431 Has my answer helped you understand the problem with your code?

Comment: Yeah it helped me understanding the problem. I tried to find a workaround with the async library but it didn't work to me.

Comment: @user3197431 Edit your question to show how you tried to solve this with `async` and hopefully we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Me again. It doesn't work. This is my current code. https://gist.github.com/podkopaev/8632141

The variable hoster is still empty.